# i wrote a code in c language to find multiplication of matrix by using multidimensional matrix and loops but it is printing address

Tags: c

I wrote a code in c language to find multiplication of matrix by using multidimensional matrix and loops ,everything is working perfectly fine but it is printing address and i have tried everything but i can't figure out what's my mistake .Anbody plz help me to figure what's the problem.A suggestion will be very much helpful

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[10][10], b[10][10], result[10][10];
    int r1, c1, r2, c2, i, j, k, sum = 0;
    
    printf("give number of rows and column");
    scanf("%d %d", &r1, &c1);
    
    printf("give number of rows and column");
    scanf("%d %d", &r2, &c2);
    
    while (c1 != r2) {
        printf("invalid matrix");
        
        printf("give number of rows and column");
        scanf("%d %d", &r1, &c1);
        
        printf("give number of rows and column");
        scanf("%d %d", &r2, &c2);
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= r1; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= c2; j++) {
            printf("enter the numbers for 1\n");
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= r1; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= c2; j++) {
            printf("enter the numbers \n");
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < r1; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < c2; ++j) {
            for (k = 0; k < c1; ++k) {

                sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
        }
        result[i][j] = sum;
        sum = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= r1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= c2; j++) {
            printf("%d", result[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\n\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `result[i][j]=sum;` must be moved up, at the end of the `for(k` loop. It is now after the `for(j` loop, so `j` is not a valid index anymore.

Comment: All loops should initialize their loop variable to zero, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several problems in your code as pointed out by people in comments:

1. While taking arrays as input, you're iterating from `1..r1`, but array indices start with zero so for an array of length n you should be iterating from `0..n-1`. This means matrix indices with r=0, c=0 have uninitialized garbage values. You would need to modify your array input loops like this:

```c
for ( i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
    for ( j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
        printf("enter the numbers for 1\n");
        scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }   
}
for ( i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
    for ( j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
        printf("enter the numbers for 2\n");
        scanf("%d",&b[i][j]); 
    }
}
```

2. While calculating sum you're assigning sum to `result[i][j]` in outermost loop, you need to do it in second loop where you're iterating columns for result:

```c
for ( i = 0; i < r1; ++i) {
    for (  j = 0; j < c2; ++j) {
        for ( k = 0; k <c1 ; ++k) {
            sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
        }
        result[i][j] = sum;
        sum=0;
    }
}
```

3. While printing the result you're iterating from `1..r1`. You should rather iterate from `0..r1-1`. So it should look like this:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < r1 ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", result[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
}
```